# How to Avoid Chaining Critical Request while loading self-hosted fonts using Fontsource?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, lighthouse

I have a React Gatsby website and I am trying to optimize its performance to achieve a 95+ score in Lighthouse.

Recently I have switched to self-hosted fonts and used the npm package [Fontsource](https://fontsource.org) which I found in [Gastby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/using-web-fonts/#self-host-google-fonts-with-fontsource).

It was quite easy to install by doing:

```
npm install @fontsource/nunito
```

and add the following imports to my gatsby-browser.js file:

```
import '@fontsource/nunito/400.css'
import '@fontsource/nunito/600.css'
import '@fontsource/nunito/700.css'
import '@fontsource/nunito/800.css'
```

Which if I understand correctly loads them as a global variable. Where I already have my to imports for font icons.

However, that created a performance issue and I have `6 chains found` in the `Avoid Chaining Critical Request` section of my Lighthouse report.

How can I reduce or eliminate the effect of this on my Lighthouse performance?

Can I reduce the priority of the load so it's at the end?

I am already using `font-display: swap` in my CSS file.

I am attempting to achieve the most optimal performance so any suggestion is appreciated.

The website I am referring to is [deep-blue.io](https://deep-blue.io) and the code for [Deep-Blue](https://github.com/ChristopherPHolder/Deep-Blue) is in a public repository.

Here is also the [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=deep-blue.io) in case that is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, my score was 85/100 on mobile and 100/100 on desktop, and it bugged me that it said, `Avoid Chaining Critical Requests` and then listed my self hosted fonts, even though I used `font-display: swap`

Although my fonts were self hosted, I switched to using the `Typekit Web Font Loader` in asynchronous mode, which I have used before for external fonts (Typekit and Google Fonts): https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

I added the following JavaScript to the bottom of my page:

```
WebFontConfig = {
    custom: {
        families: ["montserrat:400,700"],
    }
};

(function(d) {
    var wf = d.createElement("script"), s = d.scripts[0];
    wf.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js";
    wf.async = true;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})(document);
```

I had to amend my CSS from:

```
button {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

to:

```
html.wf-active button {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

The Web Font Loader adds the `.wf-active` class to the `html` tag once the font has loaded.

This immediately increased my score from 85/100 to 100/100 but it bothered me that PageSpeed/Lighthouse still said `Avoid Chaining Critical Requests` and listed the fonts. I don't know whether this is a bug, because if a font isn't used then it shouldn't be loaded.  Therefore, if the loading of the font is deferred (or asynchronous) then I wouldn't expect to get a warning about chaining critical requests.

In any case, I moved my CSS font declarations to a separate file and amended my Web Font Loader configuration to:

```
WebFontConfig = {
    custom: {
        families: ["montserrat:400,700"],
        urls: ["/assets/css/fonts.css"]
    }
};
```

The end result is a score of 100/100 and no more warnings about chaining critical requests.

I hope this helps you and anyone else looking to solve the same issue.